# Entityform Submissions in a view

Tags: 7, views

I have an **EntityForm** referenced on a node and I need to show **submissions** on a **view** where :

- Node Author can view all submissions
- Submitter view his own Submission (for edition purpose)

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using two blocks with contextual filters, one that shows up for the node author and the other for Submitters.